# Selenium RC htmlsuite error with IE

Tags: windows-xp

I am trying to use Selenium RC but I keep getting this error whenever I start the server:

> "HTML suite exception seen:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: sessionId
>   7643 doesn't exist; perhaps this
>   session w as already stopped?"

The command I use is:

```
java -jar C:\selenium-remote-control-1.0.3\selenium-server-1.0.3\selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "https://user1.apps.com/" "C:\TEMP\Selenium Tests\TestSuite1.html" "C:\TEMP\Selenium Tests\results.html"
```

However with the same command if I change *iexplore to *firefox then it works.

I need to run the test with Internet Explorer. Any ideas how I can get it working?

Answer (score 1):

go back to SRC 1.01 and you'll be able to run it.

I installed SRC1.01 in a c:\src101 directory, and SRC1.03 in a c:\SRC directory.

Just make sure everything points to the right places and it will work for both browsers in their respective versions.